# Local MySql database export

Tags: mysql

I got a local website which I have coded and has database connected to it.
Now I wish to  move my website on live hosting so how do I export my local database there???

Answer (score 0):

The `mysqldump` tool will export your database to a SQL file which can be imported to your production database.

Remember to set up backups, potentially using mysqldump!

Answer (score 0):

Use ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html )

```
mysqldump
```

I use this command

```
mysqldump db_name -u root -d | sed "s/ AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]*//g" > /path/to/dump/file.sql
```

to reset autoincrements as well (mysql dump dumps tables with their current autoincrement)